# Info about big single file (Virtual Disk) and Raid Hard disk

Tags: virtualization, raid

i've a NAS with 5 disks in RAID-5.
I used it as DataStore for Virtual Box Hard Disk. So i've for example one big (1.5 terabyte) VDI file that contain 200k files. 
I'm wondering: Is the single file good managed by physical Raid or, for example, my Nas is 'stupid' and save this single file into... a single disk and not 'straied' onto all disks ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most NAS devices use a version of linux with the linux mdadm package to manage the raid, if set up as a raid-5 you will get a situation where blocks are spread across all devices part of the array.

For more information about mdadm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm#RAID_Configurations

Comment: so, you're confirming that also 1 big file (> 1 terabyte for example) is stored with block spreaded ?

Comment: Yes, Even big files are made up of seperate blocks depending on the volume block size (512b/1k/4k etc.) those blocks are spread over the disks trough the Raid rules as in posted link.